# understand UsageStats and UsageStatsManager data

Tags: java, android, usagestatsmanager

Anybody can help me to understand UsageStats data. What is the purpose of UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_MONTHLY because i am getting data in day interval .

**Code**

```
 List<UsageStats> lUsageStatsList = lUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_MONTHLY, beginTime, System.currentTimeMillis());    

        for (UsageStats lUsageStats : lUsageStatsList) {

           if(lUsageStats.getPackageName().equals("com.whatsapp")) {

                System.out.print(" \n***********getPackageName " + lUsageStats.getPackageName());
                System.out.print("   getFirstTimeStamp " + convertTime(lUsageStats.getFirstTimeStamp()));
                System.out.print("   getLastTimeStamp " + convertTime(lUsageStats.getLastTimeStamp()));
                System.out.print("   getTotalTimeInForeground " + lUsageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground() / 1000);
                System.out.print("   getLastTimeUsed " + convertTime(lUsageStats.getLastTimeUsed()));
            }

        }
```

**result**

```
10-22 11:12:04.586 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-09-2018 13:20:40   getLastTimeStamp 09-11-2018 07:12:31   getTotalTimeInForeground 2066   getLastTimeUsed 09-11-2018 02:13:49 
10-22 11:12:04.588 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-11-2018 07:12:32   getLastTimeStamp 09-11-2018 10:16:01   getTotalTimeInForeground 201   getLastTimeUsed 09-11-2018 10:02:40 
10-22 11:12:04.589 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-11-2018 10:16:01   getLastTimeStamp 09-11-2018 13:40:41   getTotalTimeInForeground 343   getLastTimeUsed 09-11-2018 13:40:41 
10-22 11:12:04.590 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-11-2018 13:40:42   getLastTimeStamp 09-11-2018 15:38:55   getTotalTimeInForeground 34   getLastTimeUsed 09-11-2018 15:09:33 
10-22 11:12:04.592 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-11-2018 16:38:01   getLastTimeStamp 09-11-2018 17:21:51   getTotalTimeInForeground 191   getLastTimeUsed 09-11-2018 17:16:05 
10-22 11:12:04.593 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-11-2018 17:21:52   getLastTimeStamp 09-13-2018 08:17:55   getTotalTimeInForeground 1452   getLastTimeUsed 09-13-2018 08:14:50 
10-22 11:12:04.594 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-13-2018 08:17:55   getLastTimeStamp 09-13-2018 13:50:16   getTotalTimeInForeground 419   getLastTimeUsed 09-13-2018 13:39:06 
10-22 11:12:04.596 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-13-2018 13:50:16   getLastTimeStamp 09-14-2018 11:14:31   getTotalTimeInForeground 1011   getLastTimeUsed 09-14-2018 11:06:12 
10-22 11:12:04.598 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-14-2018 11:14:32   getLastTimeStamp 09-16-2018 16:14:45   getTotalTimeInForeground 3465   getLastTimeUsed 09-16-2018 12:02:10 
10-22 11:12:04.599 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-16-2018 16:14:46   getLastTimeStamp 09-17-2018 12:35:26   getTotalTimeInForeground 553   getLastTimeUsed 09-17-2018 11:16:07 
10-22 11:12:04.601 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-17-2018 12:35:26   getLastTimeStamp 09-19-2018 05:18:55   getTotalTimeInForeground 1154   getLastTimeUsed 09-19-2018 05:18:54 
10-22 11:12:04.602 2042-2042/com.tunebrains.usmsample I/System.out: ***********getPackageName com.whatsapp   getFirstTimeStamp 09-19-2018 06:03:49   getLastTimeStamp 09-20-2018 20:54:50   getTotalTimeInForeground 1520   getLastTimeUsed 09-20-2018 19:38:37
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the code / docs?

```
    /**
     * An interval type that spans a month. See {@link #queryUsageStats(int, long, long)}.
     */
    public static final int INTERVAL_MONTHLY = 2;
```

so it's the interval (of an entire month) you use for aggregating the stats you're asking to have in the given time range.

I'm guessing you get them daily because your time range is one day, isn't it? What is your *beginTime*?

Comment: thanks for reply . Please check complete log from below link

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GOeIrJXk7i06WQncpZ8SHZDLrUf7BGphozvVsfWn2hE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AtulSethi yes, so? :?

Comment: Did you read at least [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryUsageStats(int,%20long,%20long))?

Note: "The returned list will contain a UsageStats object for each package that has data for an interval that is a subset of the time range given.". There is also an example provided, so please try it out.

Comment: this is begin time which i am using

Comment: final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -3); // Set year to beginning of desired period.
        final long beginTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); // Get begin time in milliseconds

Comment: Yes @Alessio , i have read that .  intervalType = INTERVAL_YEARLY
 beginTime = 2013
 endTime = 2015 (exclusive)

 Results:
 2013 - com.example.alpha
 2013 - com.example.beta
 2014 - com.example.alpha
 2014 - com.example.beta
 2014 - com.example.charlie
 it's showing single row for each year . i have checked this is not working in my case and it s showing data in day interval if i am using INTERVAL_YEARLY

Comment: as doc like year , it should be show single row for each month if i use INTERVAL_MONTH but it's not working

Comment: @AtulSethi what about if you use INTERVAL_WEEKLY, do you still see daily instead? I mean, for sure the error / problem is on your side. Also, does your whatsapp has usage statistics for monthly period?

Comment: @AtulSethi you could also try to output your time range time-points, to make sure you're asking 2015, 2016 and 2017 like I understand you want to do.

Comment: Error must be in your convertTime(), please show that part of the code as well

Comment: For me it works as expected:

Today is 10/22/18

**Monthly (6 months expiration)**

size: 401
name: com.google.android.youtube
first: 9/30/18
last: 10/4/18
name: com.google.android.youtube
first: 10/4/18
last: 10/14/18

**Weekly (4 weeks expiration)**
size: 459
name: com.google.android.youtube
first: 9/30/18
last: 10/4/18
name: com.google.android.youtube
first: 10/4/18
last: 10/11/18

**Daily (7 days expiration)**
size: 478
// none

**now use youtube and re-run daily**
size: 480
name: com.google.android.youtube
first: 10/21/18
last: 10/22/18

Comment: public String convertTime(long time) {
        Date date = new Date(time);
        Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        return format.format(date);

    }

Comment: by which i can check for  whatsapp app in my mobile

Comment: Complete log for weekly https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mRAOpX4o54RnExkd1l_md3DdFGRT5SDb5-O2BNA5DKo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please provide complete log for this year in month interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182249/discussion-between-atul-sethi-and-alessio).